# Why loaderInfo.bytesTotal is Zero

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Why `loaderInfo.bytesTotal` is Zero when run on server but run Test Movie it isn't zero?

```
My action(Preload)


stop();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loaderF);

function loaderF(e:Event):void{
    var toLoad:Number = loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
    var total:Number = loaded/toLoad;

    if(loaded == toLoad){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loaderF);
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    else{
        preloader_mc.preloaderFill_mc.scaleX = total;
        preloader_mc.precent_txt.text = Math.floor(total*100)+" %";
        preloader_mc.loaded_txt.text = loaded+" Bytes / "+toLoad+" Bytes";
    }
}
```

Comment: Might have to do with the header your http server is sending when you request the file. Check out http://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/bytestotal_issue ; although it's for an MP3 file, the symptoms are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

it's because you need to disable GZIP for swfs on your server.

add this to your .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase          Request_URI \.swf$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

Cost me a lot of time this morning

Comment: +1 Wow, that worked for me. Never would have thought of that. I had just enabled gzip recently, and later my mp3s started having a bytesTotal of 0, but I never saw the connection. I told apache not to gzip mp3s and everything started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
```

The only problem with this is when you get `bytesTotal==0` you can't monitor load progress correctly. You only get a response when loading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter what browser? We are seeing reports this only happens in IE, not FF.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this on a swf packaged (temporarily, during development) in Google App Engine. When I moved it to Google Cloud Storage, it was fine. Sure enough, when I compared the headers, App Engine wasn't including Content-Length. I did two things to prevent this in the future:

1) I hardcoded an estimated bytesTotal as a constant, and use that to determine the percent complete (if bytesTotal is zero) for purposes of showing a progress bar.

2) I changed my preloader to be a MovieClip and use `currentFrame == totalFrames` to determine when the rest of the swf is definitely finished loading.