# What to do when loaderInfo.bytesTotal is zero

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm developing a flash file that that will be uploaded to dozens of websites which I have no control over. I found out that one of them seems to be gzipping the swf, which is causing `loaderInfo.bytesTotal` to be zero. This screws up the loading animation.

I tried a workaround of just testing if `bytesTotal` is zero, if so simply proceed. That doesn't work because, as expected, not all the necessary data has loaded yet. Alternatively I can put a timed delay of whatever the expected load time is, and hope that it covers all the bases.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? Ideally there's an alternative way to define `bytesTotal`, but I haven't found one.

FYI this is somewhat related to this question: [Why loaderInfo.bytesTotal is Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269875/why-loaderinfo-bytestotal-is-zero)

But I can't do the htaccess suggestion because I don't have control over the other websites, some of which may be on windows servers anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible you could pass the total bytes trough flashvars or have it storred somwhere in the file. 
If your using some script to define files to laod you can also et the size and pass it to flash so that event if the totalbytes is 0 you can count the progress based on the size given in some other way.

That's the only solution I know for this problem.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, that seems to have worked perfectly, I'm passing in the bytesTotal value using a flashvar. I initially tried using the flashvar version only if loaderInfo.bytesTotal was 0, however it turns out that on firefox it wasn't 0 but it wasn't correct either, it was significantly smaller than the correct value. So now I have it set to use the highest value of the two (loaderInfo.bytesTotal vs flashvar bytesTotal).

Comment: You're welcome, if you want a great loader try using the [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/). Really great library with most of the stuff already implemented. That's where I found that tehnique.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider changing your approach so that your movie can load incrementally.  If you uncheck "export on frame 1" in your symbol definitions, everything will load where it is first used/referenced. Note that this will only work if you've allowed Flash to place most of your objects on the stage for you using the IDE.  To read more about this approach, check out http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html.  Code for the article is here http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2010/04/sample-code-for-oop-timeline-insideria.html

Comment: Thanks Amy that looks like an interesting technique. But it'll require some bigger changes so I went with the idea suggested by @JakubSłaby

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Google Chrome is using his own version of Flash player. If you disable it in Chrome settings the bytesTotal will be fine. But you can't tell everyone to disable it, of course.

I found the solution how you can detect when entire loading is complete in every situation. You can check this answer: [Why loaderInfo.bytesTotal is Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269875/why-loaderinfo-bytestotal-is-zero/14964646#14964646)